# cordova-plugin-media-capture crashes IOS 13

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, media, capture

I am running an Ionic 3 app with the cordova-plugin-media-capture plugin v3.0.3. As soon as I try and run mediaCapture.captureAudio() my app crashes with no error logging. Anyone else come across this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so seems it was an error on my part as it wasnt really documented clearly, so here is how I solved the problem for anyone else. In the documentation it specifies you need to add this to your config.xml file to get permissions for IOS:

```
<edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need camera access to take pictures</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config target="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need microphone access to record sounds</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need to photo library access to get pictures from there</string>
</edit-config>
```

If you use this on a phonegap build it will crash the ios app. You need to use this format :

```
  <config-file platform="ios" parent="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription" overwrite="true">
        <string>need microphone access to record sounds</string>
    </config-file>
```